# delete from database not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#load').hide();
});

$(function() {
$(".delete").click(function() {
$('#load').fadeIn();
var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var string = 'id='+ id ;

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "delete.php",
   data: string,
   cache: false,
   success: function(){
    commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
    $('#load').fadeOut();
  }

 });

return false;
    });
});


</script>



<?php

include('config.php');
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY mes_id DESC LIMIT 20");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
        $msgID= $row['mes_id'];
        $msg= $row['msg'];

?>

<div id="<?php echo $msgID; ?>"  align="left" class="message_box" >
<span class="number"><?php echo $msgID; ?></span><?php echo $msg; ?> 
 <a href="delete.php" class="delete">x</a>
</div>

<?php
}

?>
```

I have coded this to show entries from database and a delete button to show in every div. delete.php includes code

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
echo $id=$_REQUEST['msgID'];
$sql="delete from messages where mes_id='$id'";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

but it is not working. I am not able to delete entry from database..

Comment: you may want to try removing `'` from either sides of `$id`

Comment: i have already tried this before but no use.

Comment: Also, please be aware that I can now delete everything I want by requesting "delete.php?id=1'+OR+1=1+--". Use mysql_real_escape_string to sanitise the input, and use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST: you already know where the value is coming from.

Comment: Meet [Bobbly Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I think you want to change this line:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Into:

```
var id = $(commentContainer).attr("id");
```

Because `this` refers to the clicked link, which does not have an `id` attribute.

In `delete.php` you are looking for `$_REQUEST['msgID']` but you are using `id` (not `msgID`) when you post the request, so you will need to change that to match as well.

Answer (score 2):

check your request `var_dump($_REQUEST)`
you send `var string = 'id='+ id ;`
and trying to receive `$_REQUEST['msgID']`
just change to `$_REQUEST['id']`

Comment: I have replaced `$_REQUEST['msgID']`  with `$_REQUEST['id']`,  but still not working

Comment: @user799100 what about `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Subdiggers answer, nice potential for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), see:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

Your data is wrong:
instead of:

```
data: string,
```

Where string is:

```
var string = 'id='+ id ;
```

Data should be in Key/Value pairs. so:

```
data: msgID : id
```

I made it into msgID because your `$_REQUEST['msgID']` is calling msgID.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for SQL injections! Use [intval](http://php.net/intval) on $id before inserting it into your query, to make sure it's an integer.